# Spyder 2.2.5 is giving "You should import from qtconsole instead.", ShimWarning

Tags: python, spyder

my issue, spyder 2.2.5 stopped running any code.

first of all, I have wanted to install ipywidgets but I can't because of python 2.7.6.
I updated python 2.7.6 to 2.7.12, then installed   ipywidgets with jupyter after  read [enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/spyder-kernels/) 
but seems which it just works with the last version (spyder 3.3.4), I don't sure from this information.

after installed ipywidgets, jupyter and spyder-kernels, when run spyder in the terminal, the output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/qt.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.qt` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0. You should import from qtconsole instead.
  "You should import from qtconsole instead.", ShimWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.config` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0. You should import from traitlets.config instead.


  "You should import from traitlets.config instead.", ShimWarning)
```

I read more and more before writing this post here [enter link description here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2608), the issue closed

I can't use anaconda because of some conflict with ROS library.

I can't  update the spyder because of the system of the robot depending on python 2.7.

I removed ipywidgets, jupyter, Ipython,qtconsole and spyder, then reinstalled   Ipython,qtconsole and spyder but get the same problem

output, pip freeze:

```
absl-py==0.7.0
actionlib==1.11.13
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
angles==1.9.11
apt-xapian-index==0.45
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.7.1
astroid==1.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
Automat==0.7.0
Babel==1.3
backports-abc==0.5
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.7.0.1
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
base-local-planner==1.12.16
beautifulsoup4==4.2.1
bleach==3.1.0
blinker==1.3
bondpy==1.7.20
bzr==2.7.0.dev1
camera-calibration==1.12.23
camera-calibration-parsers==1.11.13
capabilities==0.2.0
catkin==0.6.19
catkin-pkg==0.4.11
catkin-pkg-modules==0.4.11
certifi==2018.11.29
cffi==1.12.0
chardet==2.0.1
Cheetah==2.4.4
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==0.8.0
colorama==0.2.5
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==4.7.2
configparser==3.7.4
constantly==15.1.0
coverage==4.5.2
coveralls==1.5.1
create-dashboard==2.3.1
create-driver==2.3.0
create-node==2.3.0
cryptography==2.5
cssselect==1.0.3
cv-bridge==1.11.16
cvxopt==1.1.4
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.5
dask==1.1.2
debtagshw==0.1
decorator==4.4.0
DeepFried2==0.1
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
diagnostic-analysis==1.9.3
diagnostic-common-diagnostics==1.9.3
diagnostic-updater==1.9.3
dirspec==13.10
dlib==19.16.0
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.11
dodo-detector==0.5.2
door-pass==0.2.5
duplicity==0.6.23
dynamic-reconfigure==1.5.50
emergency-behaviours==1.0.4
empy==3.1
entrypoints==0.3
enum34==1.1.6
face-recognition==1.2.3
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
fake-camera-effects==0.0.16
feedparser==5.1.3
filelock==3.0.10
filterpy==1.4.5
Flask==0.10.1
flir-pantilt-d46==0.1.9
flup==1.0.2
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
futures==3.2.0
gast==0.2.2
gazebo-plugins==2.4.16
gazebo-ros==2.4.16
gdata==2.0.18
gencpp==0.5.5
genlisp==0.4.15
genmsg==0.5.8
genpy==0.5.10
gevent==1.4.0
ghmmwrapper==0.8
greenlet==0.4.15
grpcio==1.18.0
h5py==2.9.0
hrsi-representation==0.1.2
hrsi-state-prediction==0.1.2
hrsi-velocity-costmaps==0.1.2
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
human-trajectory==1.5.4
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.8
image-geometry==1.11.16
imutils==0.5.2
incremental==17.5.0
interactive-markers==1.11.4
ipaddress==1.0.22
ipykernel==4.10.0
ipython==5.8.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==0.22
Jinja2==2.10.1
joblib==0.7.1
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
keyring==3.5
kobuki-dashboard==0.4.2
laser-geometry==1.6.4
launchpadlib==1.10.2
lazr.restfulclient==0.13.3
lazr.uri==1.0.3
lockfile==0.8
logilab-common==0.61.0
lxml==3.3.3
Mako==0.9.1
Markdown==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==2.0.0
mdp-plan-exec==1.1.2
mercurial==2.8.2
message-filters==1.11.21
mistune==0.8.4
mock==2.0.0
mongodb-media-server==0.0.33
mongodb-store==0.4.2
monitored-navigation==1.0.4
MySQL-python==1.2.3
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
netifaces==0.8
networkx==2.2
nose==1.3.1
numexpr==2.2.2
numpy==1.16.1
oauth==1.0.1
oauthlib==0.6.1
oneconf==0.3.7.14.4.1
open3d==0+unknown
opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
opencv-python==3.4.2.17
openni2-launch==0.4.2
openpyxl==1.7.0
PAM==0.4.2
pandas==0.13.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
paramiko==1.10.1
parsel==1.5.1
pathlib2==2.3.3
patsy==0.2.1
pbr==5.1.2
people-tracker-emulator==1.5.4
pep8==1.4.6
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==5.4.1
pip-autoremove==0.9.1
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
pluginlib==1.10.7
pptk==0.1.0
prettytable==0.7.2
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==1.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.4
PyBayes===0.3-post-nongit
PyChart==1.39
pycocotools==2.0.0
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.3
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pydot==1.0.28
pyflakes==0.8.1
pygame===1.9.1release
pygame-managed-player==0.0.33
Pygments==2.3.1
pygobject==3.12.0
pygpgme==0.3
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
pyinotify==0.9.4
pykalman==0.9.5
pylint==1.1.0
pymongo==2.6.3
PyOpenGL==3.0.2
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyparsing==2.0.1
Pyrex==0.9.8.5
pyrsistent==0.14.11
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.14.1
python-apt===0.9.3.5ubuntu3
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-debian===0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
python-igraph==0.6.5
python-ldap==2.4.10
python-openid==2.2.5
python-qt-binding==0.2.19
python-utils==2.3.0
pytz==2012rc0
PyWavelets==1.0.1
PyWebDAV==0.9.8
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==18.0.1
qsr-lib==0.3.0
qsr-prob-rep==0.3.0
qt-dotgraph==0.2.33
qt-gui==0.2.33
qt-gui-cpp==0.2.33
qt-gui-py-common==0.2.33
qtconsole==4.4.3
queuelib==1.5.0
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.1.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.0
resource-retriever==1.11.8
robot-talk==0.0.33
rocon-app-manager==0.7.13
rocon-app-utilities==0.7.13
rocon-apps==0.7.13
rocon-console==0.1.23
rocon-ebnf==0.1.23
rocon-gateway==0.7.10
rocon-gateway-utils==0.7.10
rocon-hub==0.7.10
rocon-hub-client==0.7.10
rocon-interactions==0.1.23
rocon-launch==0.1.23
rocon-master-info==0.1.23
rocon-python-comms==0.1.23
rocon-python-redis==0.1.23
rocon-python-utils==0.1.23
rocon-python-wifi==0.1.23
rocon-qt-library==0.7.12
rocon-remocon==0.7.12
rocon-semantic-version==0.1.23
rocon-uri==0.1.23
roman==2.0.0
rope==0.9.2
rosapi==0.7.16
rosbag==1.11.21
rosboost-cfg==1.11.14
rosbridge-library==0.7.16
rosbridge-server==0.7.16
rosclean==1.11.14
roscreate==1.11.14
rosdep==0.15.1
rosdistro==0.7.3
rosdistro-modules==0.7.3
rosgraph==1.11.21
rosinstall==0.7.8
roslaunch==1.11.21
roslaunch-axserver==0.2.5
roslib==1.11.14
roslint==0.10.0
roslz4==1.11.21
rosmake==1.11.14
rosmaster==1.11.21
rosmsg==1.11.21
rosnode==1.11.21
rosparam==1.11.21
rospkg==1.1.7
rospkg-modules==1.1.7
rospy==1.11.21
rospy-message-converter==0.5.0
rosservice==1.11.21
rostest==1.11.21
rostopic==1.11.21
rosunit==1.11.14
roswtf==1.11.21
routine-behaviours==0.0.16
rqt-action==0.4.9
rqt-bag==0.4.8
rqt-bag-plugins==0.4.8
rqt-console==0.4.8
rqt-dep==0.4.9
rqt-graph==0.4.8
rqt-gui==0.4.8
rqt-gui-py==0.4.8
rqt-image-view==0.4.9
rqt-launch==0.4.8
rqt-logger-level==0.4.8
rqt-moveit==0.5.7
rqt-msg==0.4.8
rqt-nav-view==0.5.7
rqt-plot==0.4.8
rqt-pose-view==0.5.8
rqt-publisher==0.4.8
rqt-py-common==0.4.8
rqt-py-console==0.4.8
rqt-reconfigure==0.4.10
rqt-robot-dashboard==0.5.7
rqt-robot-monitor==0.5.7
rqt-robot-steering==0.5.9
rqt-runtime-monitor==0.5.7
rqt-rviz==0.5.10
rqt-service-caller==0.4.8
rqt-shell==0.4.9
rqt-srv==0.4.8
rqt-tf-tree==0.6.0
rqt-top==0.4.8
rqt-topic==0.4.10
rqt-web==0.4.8
rviz==1.11.19
scandir==1.10.0
scikit-image==0.14.2
scikit-learn==0.20.2
scipy==1.2.1
scitos-dashboard==0.1.1
scitos-pc-monitor==0.1.9
scitos-touch==0.1.1
Scrapy==1.6.0
SecretStorage==2.0.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
sensor-msgs==1.11.10
service-identity==18.1.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.3.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
smach==2.0.1
smach-ros==2.0.1
smclib==1.7.20
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
sound-play==0.2.13
Sphinx==1.2.2
spyder==2.2.5
spyder-kernels==1.3.3
SQLAlchemy==1.3.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
state-checker==0.2.5
statistics==1.0.3.5
statsmodels==0.5.0
stevedore==1.30.0
strands-executive-msgs==1.1.2
strands-human-following==0.1.2
strands-human-help==0.0.19
strands-monitored-nav-states==0.0.19
strands-tweets==0.0.16
strands-visualise-speech==0.1.2
strands-webserver==0.0.33
subprocess32==3.5.3
suds==0.4.1
system-service==0.1.6
tables==3.1.1
task-executor==1.1.2
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
testresources==2.0.1
tf==1.11.9
tf-conversions==1.11.9
tf2-geometry-msgs==0.5.20
tf2-kdl==0.5.20
tf2-py==0.5.20
tf2-ros==0.5.20
tf2-sensor-msgs==0.5.20
Theano==1.0.4
tkfilebrowser==2.3.1
toolz==0.9.0
topological-navigation==1.0.4
topological-utils==1.0.4
tornado==5.1.1
tqdm==4.31.1
traitlets==4.3.2
Twisted==18.9.0
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
twython==3.1.2
unique-id==1.0.5
unittest2==0.5.1
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urlgrabber==3.9.1
urllib3==1.7.1
uTidylib==0.2
vatnumber==1.1
vcstools==0.1.40
virtualenv==1.11.4
virtualenv-clone==0.5.1
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
vision-people-logging==1.5.4
vobject==0.8.1rc0
VTK==5.8.0
w3lib==1.20.0
wadllib==1.3.2
wait-action==1.1.2
walking-group-recovery==0.0.19
warehouse-ros==0.8.8
wcwidth==0.1.7
web.py==0.37
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.12.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wheelchair-detector==1.5.4
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
world-canvas-client-py==0.1.0
world-canvas-server==0.1.0
world-canvas-utils==0.1.0
wstool==0.1.17
wurlitzer==1.0.2
wxPython==2.8.12.1
wxPython-common==2.8.12.1
xacro==1.9.5
xdiagnose===3.6.3build2
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
zope.interface==4.6.0
ZSI==2.1a1
```

please help me or any suggestion

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You said:

> my issue, spyder 2.2.5 stopped running any code.

That version is **five and a half** years old. Please update if you want everything to work without problems.

Comment: First of all, thank you, please recommend me how I update it so that it works with Python 2.7

Comment: I updated it to 2.3.9, but get some error:An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist‑packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/start_ipython_kernel.py", line 186, in 
ipk_temp.initialize()
File "", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist‑packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist‑packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 469, in initialize
self.init_sockets()
.....

Comment: 2.3.9 is not our latest version (that's still more than three years old). It's 3.3.4, but you can't get it through your package manager. Instead, please download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux). And also remove all versions you install with your package manager because those can interfere with Anaconda.

Comment: I can't install [https://www.anaconda.com] and python3, I mentioned this in my question above, I think 2.3.9 is the latest version with python2 [https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads/]

Comment: All our versions (even 3.3.4) are still compatible with Python 2. Simply download Anaconda for Python 2 instead of 3.

Comment: anyway, thank you so much, I can't use anaconda because of some conflict with ROS library.